# Modifying styles programmatically

Tags: android, coding-style, android-preferences

In an Android application I am writing, the styling for my various `TextView` elements is defined in an xml resource. I would like enable the user to change certain styles such as `android:typeface` using a `PreferenceActivity`.

Is there a way to modify a style resource programmatically such that all associated widgets will update correctly? If not, must I manually select all widgets by id and change their styling?

Comment: Just found a project on Google Code (http://tiny.cc/axsqg). It appears to manually set `textSize` of widgets. [Relevant lines 2406, 1782, 2202.]

Answer (score 0):

Don't know whether you've found it but the Cubewallpaper sample uses preferences and that appears to do it all by hand in the **onSharedPreferenceChanged** event.

You can keep the preference keys in a resource file but that's about it it would appear.

Comment: I've realised already that I can use the `onSharedPreferenceChanged` callback to notify my `Activity` that the preferences have been changed. My problem is that I don't know how to change a style defined in an xml resource which is used by many widgets.